# iOS - Rotate UIImageView or UIImage while moving its frame with NSTimer

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation, uiimage

I need to rotate my `UIImageView`, or the `UIImage` in the `UIImageView`, while moving its frame with `NSTimer`. This is the `NSTimer` movement :

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(animate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This is the animate method (a part of it, the most important) :

```
CGRect viewLocation = [[[self layer] presentationLayer] frame];
                self.frame = CGRectMake(viewLocation.origin.x, viewLocation.origin.y + 0.2, viewLocation.size.width, viewLocation.size.height);
```

And this is the method i'm trying to use to rotate the UIImage :

```
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;
    [rotatedViewBox release];

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, DegreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

This code is inside a subclass of `UIImageView`, so self is referred to `UIImageView`.

I also try to rotate `UIImageView` with CGAffineTransform, but the `UIImageView` is being stretched and rotate in a strange manner.
This is the method :

```
- (void)rotateWithDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
    self.transform = transform;
}
```

And this is the macro :

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

The important thing is that you can always use the timer to move the object, so that part is unchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! First of all we exclude the solution that provides the resize of `UIImage`. So, we rotate the `UIImageView`, but when use CGAffineTransform the frame have NOT to be modified! So, to move the `UIImageView` with the timer we have to modify the center of the `UIImageView`. This is to delete :

```
CGRect viewLocation = [[[self layer] presentationLayer] frame];
self.frame = CGRectMake(viewLocation.origin.x, viewLocation.origin.y + 0.2, viewLocation.size.width, viewLocation.size.height);
```

And this is to add :

```
self.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2), self.frame.origin.y + 0.2 + (self.frame.size.height / 2));
```

Then, we can use the `rotateWithDegrees:` method to rotate the `UIImageView` :

```
- (void)rotateWithDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
    self.transform = transform;
    _degrees+=0.5;
    if (_degrees == 360) {
        _degrees = 1;
    }
}
```

So, we can add the line :

```
[self rotateWithDegrees:_degrees];
```

below :

```
self.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2), self.frame.origin.y + 0.2 + (self.frame.size.height / 2));
```

The `UIImageView` moves due to the change of its center, and not due to the change of its frame and this allow to use `CGAffineTransform` for the rotation.